# How to detect open circuit conductor inside opaque insulating sheath/cable

Tags: dc, basic

How to detect open circuit conductor inside opaque (untransparent) insulating sheath/cable in small scale. I meant the cable diameter only 1 - 1.5 mm with suspected spot within 10 - 20 cm length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the broken wire to 117VAC, and slide a scope probe along until the 60Hz suddenly drops.

Or inject some USB signal, and use the same scope inspection.

Comment: What is actually "a scope probe" ?  I'm sorry.. I'm kind of newbie in elecrtonic instrument expertise. (note: as nowadays is information age so anything is easily informed in multimedia, so would you upload the instrument picture)

Comment: google "oscilloscope". The usual input to an oscilloscope is by scope-probe. Usually a 10X scope-probe is used, because the 10pf-15pF Cin is acceptable load for many circuits (and MCU outputs).

Answer (score 1):

There are needle tipped multimeter probes like the ones below:
[image]

Or you can simply use "pins":
[image]